# unknown behaviour in C# windows form application

Tags: c#, class, properties, set

I have one class **Product** in several properties. 
The problem is when I set the **Count** of **Product** for **Customer** property the **Count** of **Product** for **Supermarket** would be changed too.

I have these classes and properties:

```
class Supermarket
{
    string _name;
    string _address;
    string _phoneNumber;
    List<Product> _products = new List<Product>{ };
    List<Product> _soldProducts = new List<Product>{ };
    List<Customer> _customers = new List<Customer>{ };
    private int _customersCount = 0;
 }

class Customer:Human
{
    int _customerId;
    string _bankId;
    List<Product> _purchased = new List<Product> { };
    List<Product> _purchaselist = new List<Product> { };
    float _discount;
}

class Product
{
    string _id;
    string _name;
    DateTime _expireDate;
    int _cost;
    int _count;
}
```

with debug I find out that this part will change the **Count** of **Product** in **Supermarket** BUT i dont understand why.

```
                supermarket.Customers[customerIndex].Purchaselist.Add(product);
                supermarket.Customers[customerIndex].Purchaselist.Last().Count=productCount;
```

also i removed the **Setter** Property for **Products** in **Supermarket** but the problem still exists.

for adding products I used .Add(...);

Comment: You talk of property getters and setters: but there are no such members in the code you have shown.

Comment: This is entirely normal, a customer and a supermarket reference the same product object.  At a minimum you'll need *two* counters, like InStock and InBasket.  Still not formally correct since you need to keep track of InStock for each individual supermarket.

Comment: i didnt paste them here .well i said i removed setter to make sure that nothing else will change the count of product in supermarket. @Richard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For every time adding an object into a List, you should "new" (create new instance of) that object before calling the Add() method.

```
Product product = new Product();
product._id="original value";
productList1.Add(product);
productList2.Add(product);

product._id="new value"; // this will change both object instances that you have added to the 2 lists above.
```

Another example:

```
   Product product = new Product();
   for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
       product._id=i.ToString();
       productList.Add(product);
   }
   //EXPECTED: 0 1 2
   //RESULT: 2 2 2
```

Instead, you should do this:

## UPDATE

```
        Product product = new Product();
        product._id = "fisrt value";

        List<Product> productList1 = new List<Product>();
        List<Product> productList2 = new List<Product>();

        productList1.Add(product);
        product = new Product(); // initialize a new instance
        product._id = "second value";
        productList2.Add(product);

        product = new Product();// initialize another new instance
        product._id = "new value";

        Console.WriteLine("List 1:");
        foreach (var p in productList1)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(p._id + " ");
        }

        Console.WriteLine("List 2:");

        foreach (var p in productList2)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(p._id + " ");
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Last value: " + product._id);

        Console.ReadKey();

      //RESULT: List1: first value
      //        List2: second value
      //        Last value: new value
```

Comment: can i separate it from list after adding it? in your first example after adding product to list1 and 2 changing product not affect product added in list. @FlySoFast

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary Yes you can. I've just edited the answer. Just think of the "product" variable as the pointer that points to the object. Every time you "new" it, it points to another place in the memory. If you don't, it will affect the changes to all the references of that object (for example, in the productList1 and productList2)

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary please mark this as anwser if it solved your problem.

Comment: Well it wasnt clear for me but i find out that i must use constructor and set each property with constructor witch is a deep copy...btw thanks for help

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you are using same instance of `Product` class  in `supermarket.Customers` and `supermarket.Supermarket`  .

Make sure you are creating a new instance of `Product` while adding a product to purchased list